# Using property setting to make additions and retrieval

Tags: c#

In my program, I am making currency addition from a for...loop. It is working fine. But I am not sure if what has been done is correct and in accordance with C#.

```
class Program {
    private double _amount;
    public double amount {
        get {
            return _amount;
        }
        set {
            _amount = value;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Program p = new Program();

        for (int i = 1000; i < 1300; i++) {
            double y = 30.00;
            double x = y + p._amount;
            p._amount = x;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(p._amount.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I have reduced the size of the code. In effect, however, there are several if clauses within the for...loop which I do the calculations.

I would like to thank anyone who could point out any inconsistency with C# coding principles.

Comment: `_amount` is a private property how your code is working ?

Comment: I ran the Console Application. It produces a result of amount i.e. p._amount.ToString() of 7000.

Comment: ow my bad u didn't notice that main is withing Program class ..

Comment: Declare a another class then put your same code there and your code will fire error.

Comment: Sure I will experiment. But in the present one this is the way I have done it.

Comment: Since you don't use `i` in the loop,  why do you use 1000 to 1300 instead of just 0 to 300? Why not make the property and baking field `static` instead of instancing the program class?

Comment: I added a class A and a method in the class and instantiating Program class from the class A. My code reports no error at all suitably modified for the purpose.

Comment: Ron Beyer has offered some imaginative guidance to me.

Comment: Can anyone explain why in a for...loop 1 to 300 or 1000 to 1300 makes any difference at all? This is a genuine request for improving my knowledge.

Comment: You would have to use 0 to 300 to be equivalent,  or change the check to `i  <= 300`. Otherwise it's the same since you don't use the value in the loop,  and I'd prefer to use 0 to 300 since it's much clearer you intend for it to loop 300 times.

Comment: Nice to hear. Thanks.

Comment: It would be i < 300 not i <=300 if i initializes with 0 . Also, having a getter or setter is pointless if your main never uses it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is to use meaningful names, so program could be given a more 
meaningful name.

Modularise your code (create a separate class from your program) and use the recommended coding practices by MSDN for C#.

```
class Calculation
{

    public double Amount { get; set; }

    public double run(double y)
    {
        // No need to start at 1000.
        for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
        {
            Amount += y;
        }
        return Amount;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Calculation calculation = new Calculation();
        // pass your variable as a parameter into a class function.
        var y = 30.0;
        Console.WriteLine(calculation.run(y).ToString());
        //  Console.ReadLine(); use control F5 to prevent console window from closing.
    }
}
```

[C# Coding Conventions (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx)

Comment: I started out with my rather immature C# code. On the way, Ron gave me a helping hand. And now MrsEd taught me how to really program. Thank you very much.@MrsEd. @ Ron Beyer.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend changing this code:

```
public double amount
{
    get
    {
        return _amount;
    }
    set
    {
        _amount = value;
    }
}
```

with this:

```
public double getamount()
{
        return _amount;   
}
public void setamount(int value)
    {
        _amount = value;
    }
```

Comment: No! There is no reason to remove the property and replace it with Java style code. This is a step backwards.

Comment: It is with some difficulty that I learnt C# property. I don't want to go back.as Ron Beyer has said.But why somebody has down voted me?

Comment: @Unnikrishnan your code is fine with a property,  don't do what this answer suggests. Don't worry too much about down votes,  I didn't vote on your question but the majority of questions seem to get down voted here.

Comment: Thank you Ron. I knew you did not do that. You have offered me some insight with your comments. Thanks so much.

Comment: I was just trying to help. Geez. If he doesn't want to use it then don't. From what I understood he was asking for other ways to write that.